# Scanner on Brother 420CN does not appear in Simple Scan

Tags: 11.10, usb, scanner

My scanner does not show up in Ubuntu 11.10. It is a Brother MFC 420CN USB printer. Could someone please show me how to install the driver for this printer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the brscan2 models driver located [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc420cn_us&os=128). It has scanner installation instructions [here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1.html?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc420cn_us&redirect=on). If this works for you, we can update the installation steps on this question.

Comment: both links go to an innocuous landing page.

Comment: I originally posted those in 2011, I guess the vendor must have shifted links around, regardless I have updated the links to point to the latest ones.